# Animate Button in a XIB to Move Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I would like to animate a button in a XIB to move up when the View loads.  With the code below the button moves with animation, but it moves from the new position BACK to the original position set up in the XIB.

It feels like I am missing something simple, but I've been trying to approach this different ways for hours unsuccessfully. Is this because I am animating something set up in a XIB with auto layout?  Any ideas are appreciated.

```
// Relevant Part of XIB class
@IBDesignable class BottomNagivationBar: UIView {

    var view:UIView!

    //Buttons Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var exploreIcon: UIButton!
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {

        let position: CGFloat = 10
        let x:CGFloat = self.BottomNavigationBar.exploreIcon.frame.origin.x
        let y:CGFloat = self.BottomNavigationBar.exploreIcon.frame.origin.y + position

        self.BottomNavigationBar.exploreIcon.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: self.BottomNavigationBar.exploreIcon.frame.width, height: self.BottomNavigationBar.exploreIcon.frame.height) 

    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have autolayout enabled on this view? Because if so, that will override any changes you make to the frame manually.

Comment: Also do not start the animation in `viewDidLoad`. That is too early.

Comment: add that code in override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {}

Answer (score 1):

> Is this because I am animating something set up in a XIB with auto layout?

Yes. Animation and auto layout are enemies. You animate the position, and then layout comes along and applies your constraints, which still designate the place the button started from — so it jumps back.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to use Auto Layout, you may want to consider animating the position using a CGAffineTransform.  Once your view loads, you could animate with:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {

        self.exploreIcon.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 10.0)

})
```

As was noted above, you will also want to move your animation out of `viewDidLoad` and into another function, such as `viewWillAppear`.  `viewDidLoad` is too early for animations as your app may still be launching/loading the view and your animation may not be visible.